# How to To sum value of columns to 1 unique result with the sum of all columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have  UNION ALL query which give me results of multiple rows resultset.
i want to sum value of Only rows which have Certain condition true
for example :

```
ELECT P_ID pid,   P_COUNT pcount  from
 ( 
   SELECT  pid, ROUND(SUM(pcount*1)) pcount  , OBJ_ID objId 
   FROM  SEARCH_H  
   WHERE  objId = '1' and  pstart <= ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('05/01/2018 12:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI AM'), -3)   
   GROUP BY  objId,  pid          

 UNION ALL  

   SELECT  pid,  ROUND(SUM(  pcount*2)) pcount ,  OBJ_ID objId 
   FROM  SEARCH_H   
   WHERE  objId ='1' and pstart > TO_DATE('05/01/2018 12:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI AM')  
   GROUP BY  objId,  pid  

 ) results
 ORDER BY pcount desc ;
```

Now the table is :

```
P_ID(VARCHAR2),
OBJ_ID(VARCHAR2), 
P_COUNT(NUMBER),
pstart(TIMESTAMP)
```

Data

```
1,1,1,05/01/2018 12:00
1,2,1,05/01/2018 12:00
33,2,1,05/01/2018 12:00
1,1,1,05/01/2018 12:00

1,1,1,06/01/2018 12:00
1,2,1,06/01/2018 12:00
1,2,1,06/01/2018 12:00
33,1,1,06/01/2018 12:00
```

so the results will be :

```
1,9
33,3
```

By now my results looks like this :
my problem is that each select sum its results separately
so now my result are :

```
1,3    
33,2
1,6
33,2
```

i really stuck here ...

Comment: I can't understand the logic. I think that you should re-phrase your question to better illustrate your goal ... cause based on   'so only to sum the results of all rows where the P_ID is 1'... the  `count` would be `6`  wouldn't it?? ... anyway may be some use of `case when` in your queries could help ?

Comment: i fix my question simple i want so group the sum by P_ID

Comment: ok. Now You'll have to explain why using `sum(p_count)` and `group by p_id` in the outmost `select` is not enough for you? As far as I can see -  It will give the expected results ...

Comment: fixed my question
Because and this is i guess my problem each select sum its results separately  
so now my result are :
1,3
1,6
33,2
33,2

Comment: yes they sum separately -  and then you sum **again** and group by p_id. so the result becomes  1,9 (3+6) 33,4 (2+2) ...or is it 33,3 (2+1) (why do you have 33,2 33,2 and not 33,1 33,2 - you got me confused here again) .... anyhow - still cannot understand where the problem is.

Comment: you right its : 33,1 33,2
sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to group (again) in the main query, as in:

```
SELECT P_ID pid, sum(pcount) from
 ( 
   SELECT  pid, ROUND(SUM(pcount*1)) pcount  , OBJ_ID objId 
   FROM  SEARCH_H  
   WHERE  objId = '13089' and  pstart <= ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(
     '05/01/2018 12:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI AM'), -3)   
   GROUP BY  objId,  pid          

 UNION ALL  

   SELECT  pid,  ROUND(SUM(  pcount*2)) pcount ,  OBJ_ID objId 
   FROM  SEARCH_H   
   WHERE  objId ='13089' and pstart > TO_DATE(
     '05/01/2018 12:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI AM')  
   GROUP BY  objId,  pid  

 ) results
 group by pid
 ORDER BY pcount desc ;
```

Comment: I try this but got error :
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the UNION ALL (or any type of UNION) for what I think you are trying to accomplish.

I am having some issue understanding your question, but if I'm correct maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
select p_id, obj_id, round(sum(p_count)) p_count
from (
    select  p_id, obj_id,
       case
          when pstart <= add_months(to_date('05/01/2018 12:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI AM'), -3)  then p_count*1
          when pstart >  to_date('05/01/2018 12:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI AM')                  then p_count*2
       end p_count
    from search_h       
    )
group by p_id, obj_id
order by p_count desc;
```

Comment: Thanks but im getting this error :
ORA-00904: "p_count": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

This is in the line where the "then p_count*1"

Comment: Is your table column name pcount or p_count?  I was going based on your table definition provided above, but it sounds like your column name is not actually P_COUNT.  If your column name is something other than P_COUNT replace the P_COUNT in the case statement where it says p_count * 1 and p_count * 2 with the actual table column name.

Comment: Thanks now its just dont give any result back . 
empty resultset

Comment: You may want to look at the data in your table.  I noticed in the data set you provided above there were no obj_id values of 13089 which is what you have in your query.  This means you would not get anything returned.   Also, you want to take a look at the pstart dates.  Do you have data in you table where the obj_id is 13089 and the pstart is less than or equal to 02/01/2018 or where obj_id is 13089 and pstart is greater than 05/01/2018.  If you are not looking for a specific obj_id you may want to leave off the "where obj_id = '13089' "

Comment: my mistake it is obj_id = 1